# require message is not coming?

Tags: solidity, remix

Im calling storage contract from logic contract, but when i change the owner to new logic contract,

```
Line 27 :         require(owner==msg.sender,"only owner can call");
```

This is not properly getting in the calling contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.20;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Storagecontract{
    address public owner;
    
    constructor(address _owner){
     owner=_owner;
    }
   string public name="sreeshma";

   modifier  onlyOwner(){
    require(owner==msg.sender,"only owner can call");
    _;
   }

   function setOwner(address _owner)public {
    
    owner=_owner;

   }
    
    function set(string memory _name)public {
        console.log(owner,msg.sender);

        require(owner==msg.sender,"only owner can call");
        console.log(owner,msg.sender);
        name=_name;
    }
}


contract Logiccontract{

    function changename(address add, string memory name)public{
         (bool send,)=add.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("set(string)", name));
         console.log("status",send);

    }
     function changeOwner(address add, address _owner)public{
         (bool send,)=add.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setOwner(address)", _owner));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the low-level call function will not revert anything. You can only judge whether the execution is successful based on the result in the return value (result, data).